# check sorting by year and quarter pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, date, sorting

I have a df that looks like below

```
     date      col1    col2
 0  2000 Q1    123     456
 1  2000 Q2    234     567
 2  2000 Q3    345     678
 3  2000 Q4    456     789
 4  2001 Q1    567     890
```

The df has over 200 rows. I need to -

1. check if the data is sorted by date
2. if not, then sort it by date

Can someone please help me with this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with `key` parameter and converting values to datetimes:

```
df = df.sort_values('date', key=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x.str.replace('\s+', '')))
print (df)
      date  col1  col2
0  2000 Q1   123   456
1  2000 Q2   234   567
2  2000 Q3   345   678
3  2000 Q4   456   789
4  2001 Q1   567   890
```

EDIT: You can use [`Series.is_monotonic`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.is_monotonic.html) for test if values are monotonic_increasing:

```
if not df['date'].is_monotonic:
    df = df.sort_values('date', key=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x.str.replace('\s+', '')))
```

Comment: thank you. I would like to as a first step check if it is sorted. Is there a way I can do that first please?

Comment: @user18334254 - hmm, what is reason for it? In pandas is not possible check if sorted column, only by testing sorted values by original values. So cannot avoid sorting

Comment: I am trying to build a model where I dont really need the date column, but need the other columns sorted by date. It would be easier for me if I only keep numeric fields in the df. So I want to first check if it is already sorted by date, then can drop it. I could also sort it first and then drop it, but was curious if we can check if it is already sorted, so we can maybe do it bit smarter

Comment: @user18334254 - Understand. Added new solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert your `date` column as `pd.Index` (or define it as the index of your dataframe):

```
if not pd.Index(df['date']).is_monotonic_increasing:
    df = df.sort_values('date')
```